# javafx: How to multithread windows and pass information between them?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am currently working on a JavaFX app. This app contains a main window and several different input windows, which are opened by button clicks.

The following code simplyfies my app to the necessary part of code.
As in the real app, by clicking the button in the main window the inputwindow opens. There you can input a text. So far all works well.

By clicking the submit button the input text should get transmitted to the main window somehow and the input window should close.

My idea is to open the input window in a second thread. This way i would be able to make the main window wait until the submit button notifies it to continue.
Unfortunately I don't know multithreading so far. I spent the last few days on trying to understand tutorials and examples, even though i couldn't manage to make my app able to do what i want.

Please help me with working code and explanations on it.

main window code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainWindow extends Application
{
    private Text text;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        text = new Text("no text yet");

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("define text");
        btn.setOnAction( (event) -> defineText() );

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(text, 0, 0);
        grid.add(btn, 0, 1);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setTitle("MainWindow");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 300, 200));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void defineText()
    {
        // open InputWindow
        InputWindow iw = new InputWindow();
        iw.start(null);

        // wait until InputWindow notifies


        // set text according to input from InputWindow
        String a = iw.getInput();
        text.setText(a);

        // close InputWindow
        iw.closeStage();
    }

}
```

input window code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class InputWindow extends Application
{
    private Stage stage;
    private TextField textField;


    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        textField = new TextField();

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("submit");
        btn.setOnAction( (event) -> submitText() );

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.add(textField, 0, 0);
        grid.add(btn, 0, 1);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("InputWindow");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(grid, 200, 100));
        stage.show();
    }

    public void submitText()
    {
        // notifies, so that MainWindow continues its action

    }

    public String getInput()
    {
        return textField.getText();
    }

    public void closeStage()
    {
        stage.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not launch multiple `Application` instances in single app. Start only main window and use JavaFX `Dialogs` if you need user input. Good reference: [JavaFx Dialogs](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/)

Comment: Or simply use `Stage.showAndWait` (this does not work on the primary stage of your application though).

Comment: Wow fabian you're genious! That was it and works really fine. Thank you very much!